# Drag and Drop HTML5

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

Folks, how can i update the styles of dragged element

1. Update the element which is under drag
2. Update the position/space from where the element was dragged

it seems that using

```
event.target.addClass or event.target.styles.  etc
```

updates the element which is under drag as well as position from where it was taken

please take a look at this screenshot [link](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag-and-drop#/media/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB:Drag-And-Drop,_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0_%D1%81_%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8_%D0%B2_%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5_Audiotoria.jpg), this is what i want to achieve
when dragging the element, basically onDragStart

thank you

Answer (score 1):

With this you can change style of element being dragged and keep the original style (or change it the way you like):

```js
function handleDragStart(e) {
  this.style.color = 'red';  
}

function handleOnDrag(e) {
  this.style.color = 'black';
}

let items = document.querySelectorAll('ul>li');
items.forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart, false);
  item.addEventListener('drag', handleOnDrag, false);
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li draggable="true">lorem ipsum</li>
  <li draggable="true">lorem ipsum</li>
  <li draggable="true">lorem ipsum</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks man.. this is exactly what i was looking for